# Как сжать диск в VMWare на гостевой linux?

Tags: vmware

Хост - Windows 7 проф. лицензионная, на ней VMWare 12.5.2 - работает давно и исправно без глюков, установлена с родного дистрибутива.
Стоит виртуалка ubuntu. Нужно на ней ужать диск (ранее расширенный), чтобы освободить место на физическом HDD.
Ставлю в биос виртуалки загрузку с образа СD. Загружаюсь с лайвдиска того же линукса. C помощью Gparted уменьшаю и высвобождаю нужное место. Все ок. Вырубаю виртуалку. В оболочке Варе этой виртуалки иду Параметры- Жесткий диск-Сжать диск. Пишет что успешно сжат.Ok. Закрываю VMWare. По идее после этого ожидал увидеть высвобожденное место на том HDD, который ужимал. Однако все по-прежнему и в параметрах жесткого диска виртуалки так и числится старый неужатый размер. Что не так сделал? На виртуалке высвобожденное место числится как "не размечено".
Windows не перезагружал - мне кажется от этого не должно зависеть. VMWare Tools разумеется установлена на виртуалке.